# How to achieve realistic text embedding using homographic/affine transformation or any other ways?

Tags: python, opencv, affinetransform, homography

I am trying to implement the paper

"Scene Text Synthesis for Efficient and Deep Network Training", given [here in this link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.09193.pdf).

There they have used a context aware geometry alignment by transforming a region by a homography and then embedding the text and again transforming it back using inverse homography. How to achieve the same?

The algorithmic steps are understandable through this image!!!

[image]

They have asked to use random Homography parameters, but I think homography matrix needs to be predetermined, but I tried accordingly,

```
h = np.random.random((3,3))
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(img, h, (233,217))
```

but it doesnot produce any sort of feasible result.

Comment: The realist part comes from the GAN-based Appearance Learning. The geometry part should simple opencv mapping function from the  depth maps. Where the corner point at depth map indicates how the Image looks like in 3D and how to warp it to front parallel 2D (see opencv getwarp affine/perspective function for detail).

Comment: Emm this paper says they do it randomly. but I doubt thats the case. As in this image, it is more clearly done by sort of depth based homography.

Comment: This idea they adopt from A. Gupta., A. Vedaldi., and A. Zisserman. Synthetic data for text
localisation in natural images. IEEE Conference on Computer Vision
and Pattern Recognition, 2016.    I think for sky label it can be random. But for all others where depth is relative close or flat, it cant be randomly. It is local geomertry feature generated.  You have to go though this paper first.

Comment: I can form a depth map from [this repository](https://github.com/DhruvJawalkar/Depth-Map-Prediction-from-a-Single-Image-using-a-Multi-Scale-Deep-Network) . How to apply affine transformation after that? What to do next?

Comment: SInce you have depth. it is not difficult to pick 4 points or more out form the depth view right?  then it is like a chess board calibration way of finding homography right? follow this to get rest of the code up  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html

Comment: Here in this link, [https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html) we need to  pass coordinates of the desired view, how will I get those coordinates? Because I think we don't know the desired image beforehand, right?

Comment: From the image above in the question, it seems that we will not be knowing the desired image priorly as the text embedding regions will be not be selected manually and I don't have the transformed image of that region to get the desired coordinates as required by the opencv homography function. As far as I understood, the opencv function calculates the transformation matrix between a pair of images, so where am I missing out?

Comment: I remember he mentioned random. So did he randomly selected those 3D depth point (chessboard-like corner  3D points ) as the candidate for homography? the target is that chessboard should be a standard rectangular shape.

Comment: Yes, as far as I have understood. If we select random 3D depth points as source points, how to estimate the destination points?

Comment: Find the projection of random 3D depth points and finds its projection. then The first step consists to detect the chessboard corners in the source and desired images:

    vector<Point2f> corners1, corners2;
    bool found1 = findChessboardCorners(img1, patternSize, corners1);
    bool found2 = findChessboardCorners(img2, patternSize, corners2);
The homography is estimated easily with:

    Mat H = findHomography(corners1, corners2);
    cout << "H:\n" << H << endl;

Comment: at last  warp accordinly  by To warp the source chessboard view into the desired chessboard view, we use cv::warpPerspective

    Mat img1_warp;
    warpPerspective(img1, img1_warp, H, img1.size());   replace two findChessboardCorners function by first projection. 2nd by give rectangular corner corrdinates

Comment: basically we have to know the boundaries of the objects and transform along the edge of the object, right? Here in this case above is the mat. Because the text is always aligned parallel to the edges. So, how to know the points on the edges?  ----------Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: use some sort of canny to get the 2D image corner candidates. Then randomly select points of high gradient response. The original image also has depth.  so you have Image I with its color (RGB), depth(XYZ), and gradient response(grad).   So i would recommend to get highest four gradient response and try it.

Comment: See I have tried to do accordingly. I have found the canny edge detected image and randomly selected 4 coordinates and found out the destination coordinates accordingly. However, the transformation is not as expected. **I have detailed my approach and the problem in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578126/opencv-homography-does-not-produce-the-required-tranformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578126/opencv-homography-does-not-produce-the-required-tranformation)**